# Alternative upload method for Django FileField

Tags: django, file-upload

I have some django models that use a FileField, and users have been uploading files in the admin interface. We now have a problem that some files are quite big (1-3G), which makes http upload tricky.

There is a "container" class, and then "file" classes with a FK to the container. I have used inlines in the admin gui to make this easier for the users (container class form, with file class inlines)

I have found FilePathField, which I guess will be useful to let users scp / rsync files over to the server and then browse for and add details to them, but how can I get this in the admin? Do I need to just build a new form / view that creates the objects? Is there any way to somehow override the model in a custom admin form (and thus keep all the free admin goodness), that replaces filefield with filepathfield? Any other suggestions?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: curious to see what the response is, i need to deal with this same issue soon -- lots of files from 100-200mb, uploaded via admin to S3.

Comment: I have made a form with FilePathField which works ok-ish, but needs a reload of the web server to see new files :/ - still looking for alternatives!

Comment: How can I scp a file which then is entered in the db `automatic` as a model instance? The `model` and `Filefield` attr. exist. Is `Fabric` needed?

Answer (score 2):

You mention that `FilePathField` works, but needs to have the webserver restarted to see new files.  This happens because the options are gathered `FilePathField.__init__`, which is called *once* when the module is imported.

A fix would be to re-call the field's `__init__` in the form's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.fields['file'].__init__(path)
```

(That way the directory is scanned each time the form is instanced.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want to include in the admin area. Are you looking for a way automate the file upload process with a transfer protocol other than HTTP?

If so, you could create a model with a basic CharField (or maybe a URLField), and then perform a rsync or scp copy when the object is saved. For example:

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):
   path = models.CharField()
   def save(self):
      import os
      # WARNING! The path given by the user should be sanitized; this is
      # example code only. This is a security vulnerability.

      # Attempt to rsync the target file from a remote machine
      exit_code = os.system("rsync %s /incoming/files/path/" % self.path)
      # Make sure it worked before saving
      if exit_code == 0:
         super(File, self).save() # Call the "real" save() method
      else:
         # Raise exception
```

This is a very rough example, but it should help you figure something out. You'll need to **make sure that your routine is secure** (malformed paths could allow a user to run anything they want, for example). Also, **this will likely block the Django save routine while copying over a file**, so you should look at running your preferred command in a separate process.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in transferring huge files, but if your users need to be able do that without "UNIX incantations", I would suggest looking into creating a Java applet for it. It would be a lot of work, but then you could have proper progress bar etc.